# How to get the selected pie slice?

Tags: java, oracle-adf, dashboard, jdeveloper

I have a pie chart in my oracle ADF (J Developer) page fragment but I am not able to select a certain pie slice. Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for your tag:

Selection of data items can be enabled using the dataSelection attribute. Selection can be processed using selectionListener on the server or the selection event type on the client.

From
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57014_01/adf/tag-reference-dvt/tagdoc/dvt_pieChart.html